# How can i get value on multiple input fields?

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i do to get multiple value on multiple input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813645/how-can-i-do-to-get-multiple-value-on-multiple-input-fields)

How can I get value id if I have 2 input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" id="namecity1"  name="city1" />
<input type="hidden" id="idcity1" name="idcity1" />

<input type="text" id="namecity2"  name="city2" />
<input type="hidden" id="idcity2" name="idcity2" />
```

my script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    $("#namecity" + i).autocomplete("states.php").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
      $("#idcity" + i).val(data[1]);
    });
  } //for   
});
</script>
```

I can't get value `idcity1 for namecity1`, and `idcity2 for namecity2`.
What can I do to get this value?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want to get the id of your hidden field, you get it like this.

`$('#yourControl').next().val();`

Explain:
`$('#yourControl')` 
First you get the control you need, then you just say `.next()` which will get the control behind it for you. and with `.val()` you will get the value that control has.

This should work because the value you want is always next to the textbox in your DOM.

Comment: it didn't work :(
I try to change "$('#yourControl').next().val();" with 
"<script>
$(function() {

for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
  $("#namecity"+i).autocomplete("states.php").result(function(event, data, formatted) 
  {
     $('#idcity'+i).next().val(data[1]);

  });
  }//for    
});"

Comment: it didnt work..Please help :(

Comment: How many of those boxes do you have?

Comment: it depends. it can be 1, 2, or 3, or more

Comment: if you look here http://jsfiddle.net/jX6Z4/ you can see I can get the ID of your hidden field, the reason that you cant get his value is because he doesnt have a value.

Comment: it didnt work, if using "autocomplete", the value out just to id="idcity2".

Comment: you could try to use `attr` so it is `$("#idcity"+i).attr('value', data[1]);`
After that im out of ideas too..

Comment: it didnt work :(, variable i on "$("#idcity"+i)" after "$("#namecity"+i).autocomplete("states.php").result(function(event, data, formatted)" is only read 2